# VLC sometimes mutes sound and the image freezes

Tags: 11.04, vlc

When I play movies in VLC sometimes there is no sound and then suddenly the  image freezes and everything else including the mouse pointer freezes also. Could it be a hardware problem? It doesn't happen on other players.

Comment: This sounds like a VLC bug that should be reported on the [VLC bug tracker](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to **Preferences**  and re-initiaizing vlc completely.

There remains, however, a zapping problem (vlc stops playing after changing 4 or 5 stations) that I could not solve.